# Using Parentheses in Define Preprocessor Statements

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

So I was wondering when is to use

```
 #define xxx (yyy)
```

vs

```
 #define xxx  yyy
```

My project includes a files that has its own defines such at AD0_ADMD_CT if I wanted to redefine them would I need to use (AD0_ADMD_CT) or just AD0_ADMD_CT  in the define or not?

AD0_ADMD_CT is a defined as

```
 #define    AD1_ADMD_CT     (IO_AD1.ADMD.bit.CT)
```

So it would be either

```
#define AD0_COMPARETIME     (AD0_ADMD_CT)
```

or

```
#define AD0_COMPARETIME     AD0_ADMD_CT
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference in both. In first case `XXX` is replaced by `yyy` and by `(yyy)` is second case. The convention to use brackts is to avoid logical errors that may occur. For example you define addition function as:

```
#define f(N) N+N 
int a = f(5)*f(5)
```

Expected value is 10*10 = 100 , but output is 35 because at compile time is becomes

`int a = 5+5*5+5,` so using operator preference rule, output changes.

So parenthesis avoid these type of errors.

Answer (score 5):

By adding parentheses, you are forcing the argument inside the parentheses to be evaluated before the rest of the macro body, so if you had

```
#define MULT(x, y) (x) * (y)
// now MULT(3 + 2, 4 + 2) will expand to (3 + 2) * (4 + 2)
```

It does not appear to affect your current case unless there is more to your macros.

Answer (score 2):

It's very important if you have operators in your macro. For example:

```
#define ADD(x,y) x + y
ADD(1,2) * 3 /* Should be 9, is 7 */
```

Should be:

```
#define ADD(x,y) (x + y)
ADD(1,2) * 3 /* 7 */
```

These precedence problems also apply for the arguments, as @Gi Joe says, and need to be wrapped in parens for precedence.

However, for a macro like:

```
#define MAGICNUM 3
```

It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to remember is that the preprocessor simply expands macros.  For example, if you had the following lines:

```
#define AD0_COMPARETIME_1    (AD0_ADMD_CT)
#define AD0_COMPARETIME_2    AD0_ADMD_CT

num_1 = AD0_COMPARETIME_1;
num_2 = AD0_COMPARETIME_2;
```

After the first expansion you'd have this:

```
num_1 = (AD0_ADMD_CT);
num_2 = AD0_ADMD_CT;
```

And after the second expansion you'd have this:

```
num_1 = ((IO_AD1.ADMD.bit.CT));
num_2 = (IO_AD1.ADMD.bit.CT);
```

A problem may arise, as stated in other answers, when an expression is expanded.