# Why do I need to parenthesize x and y in this define?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, modulo

I use this `#define` macro to calculate the index for an array

```
#define index(x, y) (((x) % 5) + ((y) % 5) * 5)
```

If I remove the braces for (x) and (y) such that

```
#define index(x, y) ((x % 5) + (y % 5) * 5)
```

the result is different.

Can someone explain me this behavior? I use this like this:

```
uint64_t a[25];
...
unsigned int x,y;
uint64_t C[5];
for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
  for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    C[x] = a[index(x, y)] ^ ((~a[index(x + 1, y)]) & a[index(x + 2, y)]);
  }
  for (x = 0; x < 5; x++ ) {
    a[index(x, y)] = C[x];
  }
}
```

Comment: http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html

Comment: This is the kind of question that anyone with some experience in programming will know to answer, so prepare for a lot, I mean a LOT of answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Parentheses in Define Preprocessor Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155634/using-parentheses-in-define-preprocessor-statements)

Comment: `#define` preprocessor macros are one of the most dangerous parts of C.  As you've now discovered, they do not behave in the most obvious way so use them with caution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first definition, this:

```
index(x + 1, y)
```

expands to:

```
(((x + 1) % 5) + ((y) % 5) * 5)
```

With the second, it expands to:

```
((x + 1 % 5) + (y % 5) * 5)
```

The problem is `x + 1 % 5`.  Since `%` has higher precedence than `+`, it's equivalent to `x + (1 % 5)`, which is not what you want.

When expanding macros, the preprocessor expands sequences of tokens. It does not pay attention to operator precedence.

A similar example: https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/42

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIX 1+5
#define NINE 8+1

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", SIX, NINE, SIX * NINE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, the question and the answer all in one short snippet of C code. Douglas Adams would be so proud.

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice example!

Answer (score 1):

Because the macro parameters are effectively copy pasted code:

Given this:

```
#define index(x, y) ((x % 5) + (y % 5) * 5)
```

Then this is the transformation

```
a[index(x + 1, y)]
a[((x + 1 % 5) + (y % 5) * 5)]
```

Note that first part:

```
   (x + 1 % 5)
```

That is exactly why every instructional book should mention that you should wrap macro parameters in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use:

`#define index(x, y) ((x % 5) + (y % 5) * 5)`

`index(x + 1, y)` is interpred as `index((x + 1 % 5) + (y % 5) *5)`

And since modulo (`%`) has higher precedence than `+` the result is wrong.

Take a look at the table of precedence [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Always put parentheses around your macro arguments.

Macro expansion happens before compilation, and it just replaces the text of your parameters as they are in code. At pre-compile time, there are no values to be interpreted, so parentheses are necessary to preserve the order of operations.

In your example, the macro `index(x + 1, y)` is expanded to:

```
((x + 1 % 5) + (y % 5) * 5)
```

Since the modulo operator has precedence over addition, `1 % 5` evaluates to 1 before being added to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't have to, but it could cause weird situations.  #defines do direct text substitutions, so imagine this situation:

```
#define foo(x) (x << 1)
...
int r = 1;
int y = foo( r + 1 );
```

What is the value of y?
What you would want is most likely `y = 4`.  That is add 1 to R then shift left by 1
But you actually get `y = 3`.  Why?  The direct substitution and order of operation precedence.

The preprocessor substitutes like this:

```
y = r + 1 << 1;
```

And since the shift has a higher precidence, it happens before the add.

Now, applying this to your example, in this line:

```
C[x] = a[index(x, y)] ^ ((~a[index(x + 1, y)]) & a[index(x + 2, y)]);
                                   ^^^^^^                ^^^^^
```

These parts are causing your difference, when the substitution happens without the parenthesis you get this for the first part:

```
index(x + 1, y)] .....  (x + 1 % 5) + (y % 5) * 5)
                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the problem?  1 % 5 = 1  so x is always added 1
Whereas with the parenthesis:

```
index(x + 1, y)] .....  ((x + 1) % 5) + ((y) % 5) * 5)
                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

You get the behavior you expect  x+1 , then mod 5.