# Parenthesis do in C/Embedded C #define statements

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, texas-instruments

I saw the following in a .h-file for the cc2640 mcu:

```
#define ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS         (0)
```

From my C knowledge, the compiler is told to put the value of ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS everywhere it occurs, that is `(0)`. But what is the difference in putting just `0`?

Comment: *Almost* no difference. But consider a corner case such as `sqrt ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS;` and think of what will happen in each case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Parentheses in Define Preprocessor Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155634/using-parentheses-in-define-preprocessor-statements)

Comment: thank you Eugene and Bastien, that is interesting! But: What does a programmer think if he puts parenthesis on a single value? Does that make any sense? So maybe my opening question should be more specific in "What do parenthesis do to values in that context?" or something like that. I assume, there isn't more to it as Eugene implied, actually it doesn't make any sense for a value and suggests an additional functionality that just isn't there.

Comment: I'd rather wonder why they used macros to represent constants when real constants are readily available. Also, you sometimes see people write `return(0);` in their programs, so sometimes they just don't think and/or copy bad habits from others.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Well, magic numbers are bad.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think they're referring to c99's `const` keyword.

Comment: I didn't even mean that with the `return(0)` example of bad code, I meant the parentheses. But `static uint32_t const adc_status_success = 0;` would be my choice to define a constant.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt OK, I misinterpreted your comment.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the difference in putting just `0`?

None, *if you don't write crazy code*. It is common to use parentheses for macros that contain expressions to avoid unexpected errors related to operator precedence and similar stuff when using them. In this case though, defining something as `0` or as `(0)` is the same if it's used in expressions.

What do I mean by "crazy code"? Well, the only difference between the two can be seen in something like the following:

```
void func(int x) { /* ... */ };

#define ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS 0
func ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS;       // INVALID

#define ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS (0)
func ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS;       // VALID (for the love of God NEVER do this)
```

I highly doubt this is the case though, nobody in their right mind would write such an abomination. That define is most likely out of habit.