# #define statement with switch cases

Tags: c

Could someone explain what is wrong with the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WHOLE 256
#define FIRST 170
#define SECOND WHOLE - FIRST

int main()
{
    int data = -86;
    switch(data)
    {
        case -SECOND:
            {
                printf("Match\n");
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                printf("Not Match %d\n", data);
            }
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expectation output is Match. But the actual output is "Not Match -86".

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `#define SECOND (WHOLE - FIRST)`. Always be abundant in using parenthesis.

Comment: The pre-processor chapter of your favourite C book will tell you how to write macros properly.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define SECOND WHOLE - FIRST

        case -SECOND:
```

will expand to

```
        case -WHOLE - FIRST:
```

Here, the `-` from `case -SECOND` only applies to `WHOLE`.

You should use

```
#define SECOND (WHOLE - FIRST)
```

instead. (add parenthesis)

Comment: yeah, maybe I should just be putting everything in an answer instead of a comment. Quick way of earning points. However, IMHO these kind of questions don't add that much value to the site and should be closed as typo.

Comment: Plus there are good dupes [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22155766)

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes this is a common FAQ but that's not an obvious dupe. If you can be bothered to find one, I'm happy to "dupe hammer" it all.